# Umbraco 7.6: Displaying a media picker image in a web form

Tags: image, webforms, umbraco

I'm trying to display a media picker image in a web form by using

`<umbraco:Image field="blockImage" runat="server" />`

in the .ascx, but that only generates

`umb://media/2e77abe99a4d4985af044866ba00ae93`.

I did something extensive Google searching, but found nothing else. This is supposed to work as far as I understand.

So how can I display a media picker image in a web form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have serious doubts that the new API which is being used for this works with masterpages.

The format of `umb://media/2e77abe99a4d4985af044866ba00ae93` appears when using Media Picker 2 in Umbraco. The original Media Picker has been made obsolete as this new format has some benefits.

Media Picker 2 is the default in newer version of Umbraco (7.6+ I think).

You should change the media picker you're using to use the old one, and it should start working:

[image]

Alternatively, switch to CSHTML.

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer. I switched to the obsolete Media Picker and now this is generated: <img src="{" focalpoint":="" {="" "left":="" 0.5,="" "top":="" 0.5="" },="" "src":="" "="" media="" 1003="" bg-image-2.jpg"="" }"="">. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you need to go into Umbraco to reselect the media item on that node? If you get an error in Umbraco; change it back to Media Picker 2, remove the value from the picker, change it to Media Picker 1 and select the media again.

Comment: Try going into the `umbracoSettings.config` and changing the `EnablePropertyValueConverters` option to `false`. Then republish the site to refresh the XML cache.

Comment: Gave that a try, still the same output. Besides that, is there no way to display an image of the "new" Media Picker in a web form?

Comment: Honestly, web forms are really quite obsolete... If you must go with web forms, consider using an older version of Umbraco, such as 7.3. Otherwise, perhaps you could create a macro/partial view where you render the image? The macro/partial can be written with CSHTML.